# invalid credential error -google userinfo api

Tags: oauth

I am trying to fetch the email-address of the user through the Google UserInfo API "https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope"

I am using a valid access token but am still getting the invalid crdetial error.
My app is implementing Oauth 1.0 Is it possible that the API requires Oauth 2 token.
If yes,what is the other way to get the email address of a user?

Here is my code-

```
     $('#GMAIL_BUTTON').click(function () {
    //oauth1 approach similar to twitter
    var requestUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
    var authorizeUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken";
    var accessUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken";
    var callbackUrl = "http://abcd.com/dfdf.php";
    var scope = "https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email      https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    var clientID = "vfdvfdvfd";
    var clientSecret = "dvdfvrevvfv-fvfdvf";
    var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
    var nonce = (new Date()).getTime();   
    var params = [];
    params["oauth_callback"] = encodeURI(callbackUrl);
    params["oauth_consumer_key"] = clientID;
    params["oauth_timestamp"] = timestamp;
    params["oauth_nonce"] = nonce;
    params["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1";
    params["scope"] = scope;
    var paramString = normalizeParams(params);
    var sigBaseString = "GET&" + encodeURIComponent(requestUrl) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(paramString);
    var keyText = encodeURIComponent(clientSecret) + "&";
    var keyMaterial = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(keyText, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var macAlgorithmProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.MacAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
    var key = macAlgorithmProvider.createKey(keyMaterial);
    var tbs = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(sigBaseString, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var signatureBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.sign(key, tbs);
    var signature = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);
    paramString += "&oauth_signature=" + encodeURIComponent(signature);
    requestUrl = encodeURI(requestUrl);
    requestUrl += "?" + paramString;
    var response = sendGetRequest(requestUrl);
    //requestUrl += "?scope="+encodeURIComponent(scope);
    //var response = sendGetRequest(requestUrl, dataToPost, null);
    var keyValPairs = response.split("&");
    var oauth_token;
    var oauth_token_secret;
    for (var i = 0; i < keyValPairs.length; i++) {
        var splits = keyValPairs[i].split("=");
        switch (splits[0]) {
            case "oauth_token":
                oauth_token = splits[1];
                break;
            case "oauth_token_secret":
                oauth_token_secret = splits[1];
                break;
        }
    }

    // Send the user to authorization
    authorizeUrl += "?oauth_token=" + oauth_token;

    // document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "\r\nNavigating to: " + twitterURL + "\r\n";
    var startURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(authorizeUrl);
    var endURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(callbackUrl);

    //authzInProgress = true;
    Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(
        Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions.none, startURI, endURI)
        .done(function (result) {
            var value = result.responseData;
            var callbackPrefix = callbackUrl + "?";
            var dataPart = value.substring(callbackPrefix.length);
            var keyValPairs = dataPart.split("&");
            var authorize_token;
            var oauth_verifier;
            for (var i = 0; i < keyValPairs.length; i++) {
                var splits = keyValPairs[i].split("=");
                switch (splits[0]) {
                    case "oauth_token":
                        authorize_token = splits[1];
                        break;
                    case "oauth_verifier":
                        oauth_verifier = splits[1];
                        break;
                }
            }
           if (result.responseStatus === Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.errorHttp) {
                //document.getElementById("FacebookDebugArea").value += "Error returned: " + result.responseErrorDetail + "\r\n";
            }
            //form the header and send the verifier in the request to accesstokenurl
           var params = [];
           var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
           var nonce = (new Date()).getTime();
           params["oauth_consumer_key"] = clientID;
           params["oauth_nonce"] = nonce;
           params["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1";
           params["oauth_timestamp"] = timestamp;
           params["oauth_token"] = authorize_token;
           params["oauth_verifier"] = oauth_verifier;              
           var paramString = normalizeParams(params);

           var sigBaseString = "GET&" + rfcEncoding(accessUrl) + "&" + rfcEncoding(paramString);
           var keyText = rfcEncoding(clientSecret) + "&" + rfcEncoding(oauth_token_secret);
           var keyMaterial = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(keyText, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
           var macAlgorithmProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.MacAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
           var key = macAlgorithmProvider.createKey(keyMaterial);
           var tbs = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(sigBaseString, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
           var signatureBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.sign(key, tbs);
           var signature = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);
           paramString += "&oauth_signature=" + rfcEncoding(signature);
           accessUrl = encodeURI(accessUrl);
           accessUrl += "?" + paramString;
           var response = sendGetRequest(accessUrl);

            var tokenstartpos = response.indexOf("oauth_token") + 12;
            var tokenendpos = response.indexOf("&oauth_token_secret");
            var secretstartpos = tokenendpos + 20;
            var token = response.substring(tokenstartpos, tokenendpos);
            var secret = response.substring(secretstartpos);


            var gmailinfourl = "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?access_token="+token;

            WinJS.xhr({url: gmailinfourl}).done(function success(result) {
                var gmail_id = JSON.parse(result.responseText).email_address;

                    //send data to server
                    //more code

            });
           /*

            */
        }, function (err) {
            WinJS.log("Error returned by WebAuth broker: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [userinfo email scope](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope) is this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Google deprecated the [OAuth 1 access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto) and you are encouraged to upgrade to OAuth 2 (which is way more easy!), though it should still work for a while. <strike>However, if you registered a new `client id` since the deprecation, it may be that it only works with OAuth 2.</strike>

**UPDATE:**

The problem you have, is that you try to request the resource the OAuth 2 way:

```
GET /userinfo/email?access_token=...
```

OAuth 1 works different, as you can see on [Google's OAuth 1 Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/):

```
GET /userinfo/email?oauth_consumer_key={CONSUMER_KEY}
                   &oauth_nonce={NONCE}
                   &oauth_signature={SIGNATURE}
                   &oauth_signature_method={SIGNATURE_METHOD}
                   &oauth_timestamp={TIMESTAMP}
                   &oauth_token={YOUR_TOKEN}
                   &oauth_version=1.0
```

Better yet, it would be to include the OAuth signature in the request header:

```
GET /userinfo/email
[...]
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="{CONSUMER_KEY}",
                     oauth_nonce="{NONCE}",
                     oauth_signature="{SIGNATURE}",
                     oauth_signature_method="{SIGNATURE_METHOD}",
                     oauth_timestamp="{TIMESTAMP}",
                     oauth_token="{YOUR_TOKEN}",
                     oauth_version="1.0"
```

See the [`header`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) parameter for info on how to set it.

Comment: i dont have a choice as my app has also to fetch the Gmail data which bounds me to use oauth 1 as Google does not support oauth2 over IMAP

Comment: so i registered my application after the deprecation.does that mean that I can't use the Oauth1 token.I am able to use it to fetch email over IMAP

Comment: So you already got a working OAuth token, but it does not work for other APIs than Gmail? Please provide a flow of the requests you send to Google for getting the tokens (remember to censor your credentials). Maybe you're doing the scope wrong?

Comment: When entering the `userinfo.email` scope at the [old Playground](http://www.googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) it is no problem to get a working access token. So check where your requests differ to the requests done there.

Comment: Even I was able to generate a token using the playground but when I make a request from my browser to the google API using that token to get the address,it again gives invalid credentials.

Comment: But when I use the access token in this site to use in the "userinfo/email" API it works fine.So does is it affected by the month I registered the app(after the deprecation)